# OOP with PHP ( Webservices )

Tags: c#, php, oop, soap, qlikview

I am familiary with OOP in Java or .Net world, now I'm asked to work with OOP same in PHP in my company, but it seems total different, since in PHP we don't have strong type variables and I never did any OOP before in PHP.
The task was actually to integrate an API(Qlikview) written in .NET and to do the same functionalities in PHP like in that API. Documentation can be found: http://community.qlikview.com/docs/DOC-2606

And to connect to the services, I create a new class which will be connected to ('http://:4799/QMS'). So far everything is working. But I've got an issue in changing the properties in my QMS. The QMS is installed on the server itself.

Let's say, I've following code:

```
List<DocumentFolder> DocFolders = BackendClient.GetUserDocumentFolders(QvsGuid, DocumentFolderScope.All);
```

I would write it actually like in buttom code in order to get those information that I require(QvsGuid and DocumentFolderScope.All):

```
$DocFolders=(object)array();
$DocFolders=$this->client->GetUserDocumentFolders(array('qvsID' => getQlikviewServerInfo()->ServiceInfo->ID, 'scope' => 'General'))->GetUserDocumentFoldersResult->DocumentFolder;
```

But on execution, I get:

```
 Call to a member function GetUserDocumentFolders() on a non-object
```

So I thought, I might have to create a class for $DocFolders of type DocumentFolder.

I know it might be only a focused group of people that might reply concerning the API, but I hope someone could open a new road of perspective.

Comment: First of all you have to ask what is `$this->` in that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Call to a member function GetUserDocumentFolders() on a non-object`

That error means that $this->client is not an object, more than likely its null and has not been set yet.

You have to set `$this->client` to an instance of whatever class has the `GetUserDocumentFolders` function

Comment: Yes, I actually was missing a class, I just created and it worked fine. Good tip.